# PowerBI Accessing a secured rest api

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I need help, I am new to PowerBI but I am know few stuff in Azure and C#. Anyways here is my current scenario: I am trying to get data from a REST API and show it as a report in my POWERBI unfortunately my REST API is AAD Protected so I need to provide an Access Code every time I tried to access my API. If you could point me out what should?

I usually use implicit flow to authenticate my user and for them to use my REST API but in this case is Implicit Flow still a possible solution? If not is storing Client ID and Secret safe to be store in PowerBI?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use implicit flow with MSAL 1.X which is old version but it is not a recommended for the purpose of your apps security.

You need to handle the access code to automatically pass to the server and get the access token when using Auth code flow.

Technically For your scenario, you can also use [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow#:%7E:text=%20Client%20Credential%20Flow%20%282-legged%20OAuth%29%20%201,3%20Step%203%3A%20Make%20API%20Requests%20More%20) which will not require a user credential involvement and there is no need to pass access code which is only part of auth code flow.